# Unknown column 'enseignant0_.TYPE_PERSONNE' in 'field list'

Tags: java, exception, ejb

I have a problem when I call methode :

```
@Override
public List<Cours> getAllCours() {
    Query req =em.createQuery(" select c from Cours c");
    return req.getResultList();
}
```

here is my entity Cours:
[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aB3Io.png)

Comment: Most probably you have a typo in the Enseignant or the column is missing.

Comment: the column is in the entity Person with the anotation 
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="TYPE_PERSONNE")

Comment: The question is , is it in the database. It is complaining that it is missing from there.

Comment: Ando also the query is saying that it is looking for it in the Enseignant. This is the reason why it is named 'enseignant0_.''

Comment: but there is an heritance between Enseignat and Person

Comment: I think I must add (INNER JOIN) in my query but I dont know where

Comment: so post the Table for Person

Comment: done posting ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the entity persone

[Person](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o9a4.png)